# yajra datatables keep index column on search

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable, laravel-datatables

I have a data collection and I have added a column with index:

**BACKEND:**

```
Route::get('user-data', function() {
    $model = App\User::query();

    return DataTables::eloquent($model)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->toJson();
});
```

**Frontend:**

```
              { data: 'DT_RowIndex', 'orderable': false, 'searchable': false },
              { data: 'name' },
              { data: 'email' },
              { data: 'phone' }
          ]
```

It gives a perfect result, but I need to keep the index when I filter the table by name.

For example if Mr. Smith is the number four in the list, when I search him datatables hides the other results that don't match and gives him number 1. I need it to keep number 4.

Comment: I think you have an `id` column on your table, you can use that here. `data: 'id'` instead of `data: 'DT_RowIndex'`

Comment: No, I don't have the id column, because ids are very different from index. I need to use index.